# Without using CV2, how do I display an image showing only the isolated green colors

Tags: python, image-processing, spyder

My goal is to read an image of a plant and then output the picture showing only the green parts without any other background colors.  Essentially, I only want to extract the leaf part from the picture and not the soil or anything else.  So far I've been able to read my images and change them to green, however my goal was to actually extract the green rather than change the whole green.  Any ideas on what I might doing wrong?

HERE IS MY CODE

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# Read and display picture
originalImage = plt.imread("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Image for detection1.jpg")
imgplot = plt.imshow(originalImage)

# Copy 1st picture and turn into an array
edittedImage = originalImage.copy()

arr = np.asarray(originalImage) # create array for image

lowerGreen = np.array([130,137,10]) # define lower values for green
upperGreen = np.array([220,235,130]) # define higher values for green


for color in arr: # loop through pixels to find the color green
    if color >= lowerGreen and <= upperGreen:
        print (color) # print the image showing only the green sections


imgplot = plt.imshow(edittedImage)
```

ERROR MSG: 
  File "C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/extract green.py", line 28, in 
    if color >= lowerGreen and color <= upperGreen:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune Ok, I'll get my MCVE code and edit the post.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With OpenCv (cv2 module), I would do as follows:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('MyImage.jpg')

hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# range of colors to filter by; you can adjust these parameters to fit your image:
lower_red = np.array([40,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([170,200,180])

# select parts of image in color range
mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
res = cv.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)

cv.imshow('res',res) 
cv.waitKey() & 0xFF
```

Comment: This (computer vision with plants) just so happens to be an integral part of the project I have been working on professionally for the past 6 months. If you have any other questions about your project, feel free to DM me in the future!